# How to represent iOS custom url schema in a link in email to open my app

Tags: php, ios, email

I am working on an app which includes user registration. On user registration, user will receive an email to verify the account. So, in the email we need to send a link and on clicking that link we open our app in mobile and does the necessary verification and confirms user.

So, my app has registered an urlschema like say "verification". So, for testing if i open "verification://userverification?userid=xx" directly in safari, it opens the app. So, now the requirement is i need to get the above link in the email so when user clicks on it we open the app. But the issue is in the email template when we use this url in hyperlink, i am seeing as follows "http://verification//userverification?userid=xx", so when clicking on it am not able to open the app.

Can someone please help me out how to send this custom url as the link in email.

Thanks
Kalyan

Comment: i think you want deeplink to your app???

Comment: yes jay.. i want to deeplink my app.. i was able to open the app from safari as i said above... but when clicking the link in the email, i was not able to... i think the problem is with formation of link.. i am getting http:// added in the link in email.. i want to be able to open my app on clicking the link..